# Ruby Net::FTP, extract filename from ftp.list()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using the following code to try and get all files from ftp using Ruby.

```
files = ftp.list()

files.each do |file|
  ftp.gettextfile(file)
end
```

The problem is ftp.list returns a whole line of information, not just the filename e.g.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ftp ftp              0 May 31 11:18 brett.txt
```

How do I extract the filname from this string?

Many thanks

Comment: Solved.

Ahh I should use ftp.nlist() to get filenames only.

Comment: ftp.nlst, not ftp.nlist.

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [nlst](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/ftp/rdoc/Net/FTP.html#method-i-nlst) public method like this

```
files = ftp.nlst("*.zip")|ftp.nlst("*.txt")|ftp.nlst("*.xml")

#optionally exclude falsely matched files
exclude = /\.old|temp/ 

#exclude files with 'old' or 'temp' in the name
files = files.reject{ |e| exclude.match e } #remove files matching the exclude regex

files.each do |file|
  #do something with each file here
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the output of ftp.list you may find  [net-ftp-list](https://github.com/stateless-systems/net-ftp-list) useful.

Answer (score -2):

However, `list` appears to be useful, as you can pass in a matching pattern, which it doesn't appear that `nlst` supports.  I just did a quick-and-dirty hack to make list output work:

```
ftp.list("*.zip") do |zipfile|
  zipfile = zipfile.split(/\s+/).last
  # ... do something with the file
end
```